# How to pass a row into a javascript function when wrapped?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a button that when clicked, it will remove the row from the table. The problem is that I cannot use 'this' to pass an instance of itself into the function because it is wrapped in a 'a href' hyperlink.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a  href="#" 
            onclick="return removeContact(\''.$row['ContactMail'].'\', this);">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: Concerning your function, could you please add the code for `removeContact`? One error I see right away, is that you are not closing the `a` tag and don't have any content in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.parentNode` to get the TD or `this.parentNode.parentNode` to get the row.

Comment: From there, if I have no tr id's `<tr id="blah"` then how do I use this row object to manipulate `.display` and `.visibility`?

Comment: you don't need an id to manipulate an element, you just need the element/object. `this.parentNode.parentNode.style.visibility = false` .

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put some Id into TR tag and call it using the jQuery wrap like this:

```
$("#TrNNN").remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to do this is with JQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  this.parentNode.parentNode.remove()
});
```

Comment: This effectively makes it so when any link is clicked, its parent table row is deleted.

Comment: This is why I hate jQuery. It's not the answer to everything. You're recommending a huge dependency to solve a single-line problem. Learn javascript first as use jQuery for complex tasks.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's the answer to everything. 
If you look at what he's also doing, creating a function to remove the record, he's basically reproducing an already existing JQuery function. The reason why this solution might work for him is that often times you're not dealing with a record. Usually multiple. This allows him the flexibility to either hit all links or if he gets a class into that selector, hone into the ones he has. As for using JQuery in general, I'm pretty well seasoned in Javascript. I just think recreating functionality that already exists is a waste of time.

Comment: the fact that he's using a **this** tells me that there's the slight chance that there could be _many_ of these links to deal with..

Comment: You'd actually have to use `$(this.parentNode.parentNode).remove();`.  The Plain Ol' JS(tm) would look something like a variation of `this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode)`, though hopefully with objects properly stored in variables.

Comment: @SpliFF, the benefit of using jQuery is that some parts of javascript is implementet differently in different browser, jQuery deals with almost all those quirks so that you do not have to, And should a new one surface, you just update to a newer jQuery and also, many more complex things you like to do is very hard to get right on the first try so using jQuery can save you a looot of development time.

Comment: @Andy: Are you sure? I'm pretty sure the **this** is using the context of the now selected **anchor** tag.

Comment: @Paul: that's correct, but it's not a jQuery object wrapping the element, so you're accessing native DOM properties/methods, for which `remove()` doesn't exist.

Comment: You could also use `$(this).parentsUntil("TR").remove()` This will work it self up from this until it finds a TR element and remove that. http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/

Comment: ahhh! that makes sense! good call! out of curiosity, does the JQuery object really just do a behind-the-scenes document.getElementByID() to setup that context?